# Can I replace an existing town's mayor?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I'm asking this question because in my mayor save file, my character's eyes are a kind that I don't like. It has been bothering me for a while, but I have recently found out that you can determine your eye type with the way you respond to Rover's questions at the beginning of the game. I would like to find out if I made a different save file with the eye type that I would like, and then ***delete*** my mayor save file, would my new villager save file become mayor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to do delete the Mayor of a town. The only option is to re-create your town.

When Isabelle asks you "**Shall we get you started?**" on the main screen, the process of deleting a character is usually "**I need help first...**" -> "**Demolish my home.**" If you do this on any other character except for the Mayor, that character and his/her house will be removed from the game.

However, if you attempt to do this as the Mayor, Isabelle will initially freak out, and then start to cry, explaining that the town cannot function without a Mayor. Instead, she offers the suggestion that if you *really* want to start over, you'll have to select "**Re-create the town.**", which will erase both the Mayor, the town, and all of its citizens.

Comment: I understand. So the only option for me to create a new mayor would to be demolish the town? Or is there another way to change your character's eyes?

Comment: The only aspect of your character's eyes that can be changed is the colour. After having unlocked Shampoodle's for at least 14 days, Harriet will begin to offer you the ability to change your eye colour. Otherwise, if you're only concerned about the face, it would be better to restart.

Comment: @Animal-Crosser I dislike the appearance of my character's eyes, but I fortunately came across a pair of Pilot Shades very early on in the game and haven't had to see that blank stare since.  Check the accessory shop daily, and maybe you'll have a similar experience.

Comment: @HyperAnthony Coincidentally, today I had the chance to go to my brother's town, who happened to have some pilot shades. Thanks for your help! ^u^

Comment: I see you mentioned you have a brother who owns Animal Crossing also. I had an issue with the way my town was set out (I didn't know I could have picked from 3 other maps!) so I went to a friend's town who I trust and gave her a whole bunch of my stuff that I couldn't possibly part with and then restarted my game. Then I went back and collected it from her. If it bothers you that much, I recommend doing that :)
The only other issue is the museum and bells you may have stacked up. Painful to catch all those things you just don't care about anymore!

Answer (score 1):

This was pretty much answered by teacupgrunge in a comment which I didn't notice before but I feel it deserves a spot as an answer on the list

If you have a friend or sibling that you really trust, ask them for help then bring all of your items you've acquired and want to keep over to their world and start over. Then go back to their town and grab all of your stuff and bring it back.

If you are far along in the game, you will lose all progress in the museum and with all the shop upgrades. So for someone like me who is considering doing this but has been playing for a month now its gonna be rough but if you are only a few days into the game I think this option would work fine.

Honestly I think this is worth it for me because I don't want to have to look at my characters ugly mug all day or wear nothing but the jesters mask 24/7. But however you want to go about it is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like your eyes or face on Animal Crossing New Leaf, then another option (other than your town) is to choose "Make Over" in the hair salon. You can then choose a Mii face as your character and it is removable.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't like your face but want to keep your stuff, I suggest making another account and using a face guide, then giving some of your stuff to the new account. Then you have a fashion model to play as whenever you want, plus you still get to be mayor. It's a win-win! :D

Comment: How exactly is that a win-win? If you want to do mayor stuff, you would have to switch back and forth between your "fashion model" and mayor. I'd say, that's quite tedious.